# Is communication via web services standardized among JavaScript on different browsers?

Tags: javascript, web-services

I'm new to JavaScript and want my JavaScript code to communicate with some server using JSON.

Imagine I write a piece of code in pure JavaScript (no frameworks), which sends a request and receives a response. If this code works in Chrome, can I assume that it will also work in other major browsers?

In other words: Is it necessary to use an abstraction layer (similar to jQuery for UI) for communication via web services?

Comment: Modern web browsers essentially implement XMLHttpRequest the same way (from a JavaScript programmer's standpoint).

Comment: *If this code works in Chrome, can I assume that it will also work in other major browsers*. No. Absolutely not. For Javascript, the sad state of affairs is that any piece of code you write should be checked for cross-browser compatibility. Even in working with long-standing AJAX functions. I mean look at this [Compatibility Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_Compatibility). The more Javascript you write, the quicker you'll be able to distinguish between what will and what won't work cross-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this code works in Chrome, can I assume that it will also work in other major browsers

assuming you will be creating a `httpRequest` object and the appropriate fallback for what ever browsers you are using, then you can presume that it will work across browsers, providing the appropriate fallback for the `httpRequest` object are in place. check this out for a snippet of a cross [browser request object](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html), you'll see why people might use a lib (ie6 support if you must)

> Is it necessary to use an abstraction layer (similar to jQuery for UI) for communication via web services

Depends, using jquery's `$.ajax` method can save you some time but isnt required. however, if you are supporting a lot of legacy browsers then it **might** make sense to use a lib that has already done all the inconsistency work for you.

You certinly dont need anything as big as jquery though, check out [reqwest](https://github.com/ded/Reqwest) and there is also [micro.js](http://microjs.com/)[1](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html) which is a tool to select micro libs based on your needs (rather then a huge lib like jquery when you only want some of it's functionality.

N.B. if you are going to hit any cross browser issues, its more likly to be what you do with the web service response and how you handle/validate the data rathe then the request itself. read up on guard clauses and a [js guard clause article here](http://blog.howarddierking.com/2014/03/24/javascript-guard-clauses.html)

Comment: I will use this code to get some data, which then will be rendered by CesiumJS ( http://cesiumjs.org/ ). The application is brand-new, I'm just starting to write it. Any ideas, which library is best in this situation?

Comment: under the hood they all do the same thing, the request is always made the same way once you get down tot he nuts and bolts

Answer (score 2):

No it is not necessary to use any library like Jquery for communication.These libraries help you to write code easily.You can simply make XMLHttpRequest get data from the webservices

Jquery code

```
$.ajax(someurl, {
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('success')
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('error')
  }
});
```

Javascript code

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","someurl",true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {  
  if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {  
    if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {  
      console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)  
    } else {  
       console.log("Error", xmlhttp.statusText);  
    }  
  }  
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depending on the browser and the browser version.

Most browsers have the XMLHttpRequest object which is used to make ajax requests to a web resource.

However, older versions of Internet Explorer do not have the XMLHttpRequest object. Older IE versions use, the IE only, ActiveXObject and pass in either "Msxml2.XMLHTTP" or "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" into the constructor, again depending on the version of IE.

Then some browsers that do have the XMLHttpRequest object have it at level 1 and some at level 2 which makes the methods of downloading binary blob data different.

So I guess it really depends on which browsers you are targeting and what kinds of data you want to exchange.

If you are making frequent Ajax requests I'd recommend a library. I use either jQuery or a lightweight library called [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be better to use jQuery or some other framework for all of your calls as they tested, reliable & if you get any bugs you will have a big community working on it.